# laravel - null value in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

i would like to know how  to solve this problem. Im making a query with a "whereIn" clause (In this case, its named "Price") in which there is a "<=" operator. But im getting an error which indicates that one variable is null. Im using laravel 5.4.

code used so far:
controller:

```
function catalog(Request $abc) {
    $categoryesc = $abc->categoryesc;
    $manufaesc = $abc->manufaesc;
    $priceesc = $abc->priceesc;
    $modelesc = $abc->modelesc;
    if (empty($modelesc)) {

        $robots = DB::table('robots')->whereIn('Category_id', [$categoryesc])->whereIn('Manufacturer_id', [$manufaesc])->whereIn('Price', '<=', $priceesc)->get();
    }elseif (Auth::check()){
        $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Model', $modelesc)->first();
        $colours = DB::table('colours')->pluck('Colour', 'id'); 
    }
    else {
        return redirect('login');
    }
    return view('catalog', compact('robots', 'categories', 'colours')); 
}
```

blade file:

```
@if (empty($_GET['modelesc']))  

<h1>Catalog</h1>

{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) }}
    {{ Form::select('categoryesc', ['3,2,1' => 'Any Category', '1' => 'Light', '2' => 'Medium', '3' => 'Heavy'], '3,2,1') }}
    {{ Form::select('manufaesc', ['2,1' => 'Any Make', '1' => 'Xenon', '2' => 'Tauron'], '2,1') }}
    {{ Form::select('priceesc', ['1000000' => 'Any Price', '100' => '100', '200' => '200'], '1000000') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
{{ Form::close() }}



<div>Available models</div>
<b>On this page ({{ $robots->count() }} robots)</b>

<div id="area1">
@foreach($robots as $robot)
  {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('modelesc', $robot->Model) }}
  {{ Form::submit($robot->Model) }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
</div>

@else

<h1>Orders</h1>

<a href="/catalog"><button> < </button></a>

{{ Form::open(['method' => 'POST']) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('users_id', Auth::user()->id) }}
  Model: {{ Form::text('Model', $robots->Model) }}<br><br>
  {{ Form::hidden('Category_id', $robots->Category_id) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('Fabrication_date', date('Y-m-d')) }}
  Choose colour: {{ Form::select('Colour_id', $colours) }}<br><br>
  {{ Form::hidden('Order_status_id', '1') }}
  {{ Form::submit('Order') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
@endif
```

In `the builder.php i previously added the "<=" operator to the function "invalidOperatorAndValue" at page 615 (in order for it t`o work). This is the error message:

```
ErrorException in Builder.php line 766:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
in Builder.php line 766
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argument supplied for 
foreach()', 
'C:\\Users\\Joao_Carvalho\\Laravel\\MegaRobot\\
vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php', 
766, array('column' => 'Price', 'values' => '<=', 'boolean' => null, 'not' 
=> false, 'type' => 'In')) in Builder.php line 766
at Builder->whereIn('Price', '<=', null) in CentralController.php line 26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `whereIn` for the condition on Price should be a `where` instead. `whereIn` is not the appropriate method for when you want to do a comparison with `<=`:

```
DB::table('robots')
    ->whereIn('Category_id', [$categoryesc])
    ->whereIn('Manufacturer_id', [$manufaesc])
    ->where('Price', '<=', $priceesc)
    ->get();
```

`whereIn` on the other hand should be used for testing whether a value is in an array, which is what you do in the two other cases.

Answer (score 0):

WhereIn expects array as a second parameter as it is structured to check if field value is within the array.

whereIn('Price', '<=', $priceesc) will  not work as second parameter is string and internally its expecting array and doing foreach on it.

You need to replace it with :

```
where('Price', '<=', $priceesc)
```

Comment: the problem is that i cant get the first option which is all the price options. In fact it seems that not even whereIn can pull the trick. Then how can i do it? i have made some other research, and it appears that i need to use Jquery. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is the `whereIn` issue addressed by the other answers.

However, in addition to that, the actual issue you're running into is that `$robots` is being set to two different things depending on the result of your `if` statements.

Inside `if (empty($modelesc))`, `$robots` is being set to a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects. When you `foreach` this result, you will loop through the `Collection`.

However, inside the `elseif (Auth::check())`, `$robots` is being set to an individual `stdClass` instance (you have used the `first()` method). When you `foreach` this result, you'll be looping through the properties on that one instance, which is not what you intended. One of the properties on this instance is `null`, which is what you are seeing.

A quick solution would be to wrap this result in a new collection:

```
$robots = collect([DB::table('robots')->where('Model', $modelesc)->first()]);
```

Comment: Actually that is what i intended. Im sorry for not posting the entire blade file code. i have updated the first post. This is a catalog and orders page. when i choose one model i get the properties of that robot and then finally order it. Now what it want (i think i will open a new thread for it) is to have the first option in the "selects" that gets all the values. Ex "any makes" gets all manufacturers.